# Disable Bootstrap accordion after opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a multiple bootstrap accordion running and would like to disable once clicked. One tab has to remain open at all times.

For example, Link1 is already open so link1 should be disabled. Only link2 and link3 should be clickable. How should I achieve this?

Here's the code:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1">
    Link 1
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2">
    Link 2
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3">
    Link 3
  </a>
  <div class="collapse in" id="collapseExample1">
    This is the description 1
  </div> 
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
    This is the description 2
  </div> 
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
    This is the description 3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

JSFiddle Link Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19604/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the classes `collapse in` from the element for which you want to disable accordion. Like here it is `link1`.

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
$(".collapse.in").removeClass('collapse in');
```

I hope this is what you wanted. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/DTcHh/19607/).

**Update:**
[Final Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/DTcHh/19611/) with a proper solution.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something. The demo doesn't do what I would like it to do. Thank you though.

Comment: I am sorry as I misinterpreted the question. I hope this is what you wanted to do - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/3vgaxxfs/1/

Comment: Thank you. I guess I didn't explain properly. I need to hide Link1 content when Link2 or Link3 is clicked and vice versa. Example: If link 2 content is open and a user clicks on Link1, Link 1 content should be shown and hide link 2 content. Now that link 1 content is shown, clicking on Link 1 now should continue showing link 1 content and not hide it. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Oh now I get that. I feel silly now :) I have added to Michael Oakley's answer for disabling link 1. Check his updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/DTcHh/19611/

Comment: Awesomeness. I hope Michael doesn't mind if I select this answer as solved :)

Answer (score 3):

This would give you that result.

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});

$('a').on('click',function(){
  // enable all 
  $('a').each( function(){
     $(this).removeAttr('disabled')
  })
  // disable me
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
})
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19608/

Comment: Can we disable link 1 by default since link 1 content is already loaded? Currently, link 1 is open and so clicking it hides the content.